# Is it possible to test web apps using MonkeyTalk?

Tags: monkeytalk

I want to automate web application or website testing using MonkeyTalk. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It is possible to test web application using MonkeyTalk. Try the latest MonkeyTalk Professional 2.0.1 edition for more functionalities.

Comment: Thank you vivek. But MonkeyTalk Professional tool is free or payed?. Can we automate web application testing using MonkeyTalk Community version?

Comment: Yes,It is open source and you can automate web application testing.

Comment: Whether agent installation and settings are same as iOS/Android app or different.

Comment: All procedure are same. All you need is source code of the web app. You can refer this: https://www.cloudmonkeymobile.com/monkeytalk/

Comment: Hi vivek, How to verify the place holder text using monkey talk verify  command?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to verify place holder text. Better you try once.

Comment: Is it possible to verify UIButton status (Enabled or Disabled) using monkey talk command?

Comment: There is not a specific command for it but you can do it using `verifyImage` command.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK - It is possible to test a **mobile** web app but not a web-app...

I mean - the actual testing (scripting and running of the test) occurs within the proprietary browser app, released by monkey talk.
So - you can't really test "regular" browsers on the mobile and especially not on a desktop.